# PHP Curl GET & POST

Tags: php, curl

I'm curling a URL with the following code at the moment, which works fine with either the get attached to the end of the URL or the POST data. But not with the get and the post.

However when I use the advanced rest client (add on for google chrome) it works just fine. Annoyingly though, I can't see the request that it sends to mimic it.

Heres the call i'm making with it.

```
$fields = array(
        'searchPaginationResultsPerPage'=>500               );
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.microgenerationcertification.org/mcs-consumer/installer-search.php?searchPaginationPage=1' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 80);  
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);
```

Just using this as a bit of a test more than anything else, but can't seem to get it working. I can get the first 500 results all the time, but not the next 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
$fields = array (
        'searchPaginationResultsPerPage' => 500,
        'searchPaginationPage' => 1 
);

$headers = array (
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19",
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch",
        "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" 
);

$fields_string = http_build_query ( $fields );
$cookie = 'cf6c650fc5361e46b4e6b7d5918692cd=49d369a493e3088837720400c8dba3fa; __utma=148531883.862638000.1335434431.1335434431.1335434431.1; __utmc=148531883; __utmz=148531883.1335434431.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); mcs=698afe33a415257006ed24d33c7d467d; style=default';
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.microgenerationcertification.org/mcs-consumer/installer-search.php?searchPaginationPage=1&searchPaginationResultsPerPage=500' );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 80 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

$str = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );

echo $str;
```

You needed cookie information and make sure curl is using GET not POST

See Demo : http://codepad.viper-7.com/gTThxX    (I hope the cokkies is not expired before you view it )

Comment: Did you try this before suggesting the obvious?

Comment: I think probably not since you will find your code gives the same problem i am asking about in the main body of this topic.

Comment: ` I can get the first 500 results all the time, but not the next 500` tested it  .... is there something you think  missed ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that fails, looks fine.. What happens when you skip CURL and go for the PHP stream method:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'searchPaginationResultsPerPage' => 500
    )
); 
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://www.microgenerationcertification.org/mcs-consumer/installer-search.php?searchPaginationPage=1', false, $context);
```

Comment: $postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'searchPaginationResultsPerPage' => '500'
    )
); 
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://www.microgenerationcertification.org/mcs-consumer/installer-search.php?searchPaginationPage=1', false, $context);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($result);

echo $html;

Comment: Tried this and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the page you are scraping and noticed the following:

- When you change the results per page it posts your search again
- They appear to be using the session to store your search parameters

You are not preserving the session ID when using CURL (and doing so is probably a bit more complex than you'd like) so this will not behave the same as on the website.

I did notice however that if you append the searchPaginationResultsPerPage parameter to the URL it works fine.  Like this:

http://www.microgenerationcertification.org/mcs-consumer/installer-search.php?searchPaginationPage=0&searchPaginationResultsPerPage=500

That means you could actually use file_get_contents and not worry about the CURL stuff.

Comment: I have tried getting the second 500 pages with the method your suggesting and it does not work, only the first 500.

Comment: Then you will need to preserve the session ID. What's probably happening in their code is if you don't have a search key stored in the session you get the first page by default. If you don't preserve the session ID between CURL requests it's like a new session every time. Read about CURL and cookies here: http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-cookies-example/

Comment: I did fear that this would probably be the problem. Weird that it works in both REST clients i've tried straight up.

Comment: Yeah the rest clients probably automagically detect and preserve the session information. This sort of stuff is always a pain, good luck :)